# Java (Windows): launch application with fresh env vars

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I want to launch a terminal (`cmd.exe`) from a Java application on Windows. For now it inherits the environment variables from the Java application, meaning the state of environment variables that were available at the time of the Java application start.

How I need to invoke the `cmd.exe` from the Java application, so it will get all the **current** environment variables, e.g. if the user has changed the PATH while the Java application is running (to avoid having to restart the Java application)?

The core problem seems to be how to access the **current** environment variables from a (Java) application - instead of the state at the application launch time.

Comment: There is no way in Java to change the current environment variables, so your question is not applicable. Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?

Comment: For example, you said "if the user has changed the PATH while the Java application is running", but Java doesn't allow you to change the PATH variable while it's running.

Comment: In pure Java you only have access to the environment variables at the start of the application using `System.getenv()`. When launching a process, I can specify different environment variables that should be passed to the subprocess. But how can I find out, what is the current state of the Windows environment variables (so the terminal will launch with the current environment variable state)? On Windows this seems possible somehow - launching a terminal from Altap Salamander (C++ application) uses the latest environment variables state.

Comment: The environment variables that you define in the Control Panel are saved in the Windows Registry (for both System and User environment). When a process is started from the Desktop, that is in fact a subprocess of Windows Explorer. Explorer reads the environment from the Registry and uses that for the subprocess that it creates. You could do that in Java using native code (i.e. the Java Native Interface). I think, as a shortcut, you can also call ShellExecute (from shell32.dll) (but I'm not 100% sure it reads the environment from the registry).